# XML callback of BestBuy API

Tags: xml, callback, best-buy-api

I was implementing BestBuy API. I have seen it's JSON callback url. Can anyone tell me xml callback url?

I have written this query

```
String url = "https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products((search="+keyWords+"))?apiKey=myApiKey&callback=XML_CALLBACK&format=xml";
```

But it gives me nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the search documentation:
https://bestbuyapis.github.io/api-documentation/

Here is a curl example of searching by wildcard product name with an xml response:

```
curl -v 'https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name=contigo*)?format=xml&show=sku,name,salePrice&apiKey=myApiKey'
```

Comment: "https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name="+keyWords+")?format=xml&show=sku,name,salePrice&apiKey="+API_KEY

Comment: This is what I have written in my code but it gives no result!